# Preview Image to be uploaded can't be shown on the page in Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, image

I want to preview an image prior to upload it, and for that I have the javascript code below:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        $('#blah').show();
    }

}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#action-icerik").on("change", "#file", function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#action-icerik").on("click", "#file_input_image", function(){

        $("#file").show();
        $("#file")[0].click();
        $("#file").hide();
    });
});
```

It seems it works properly in pc and ipad but not android phone. Normal usage is that when I click photo upload image (#file_input_image), the "browse" windows comes, I choose the uploaded image (click ok), then preview image is placed on the window.

In android phone, there may be random behaviour. But my observation is that: If I select the photos in "Photos" directory, the preview comes normally, but if I attempt to change the photo, this time page is refreshed when I selected the second photo. The photos in "Galary" directory are more problematic, the page is generally refreshed when I selected an image in this directory.

What do you think about this problem?